# dataraw doesn't contain a key although it contains

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code:

Now I want to bind that data to a listview.

This is my code

```
var results = ZumaDa.GetCustomerInformation(CallerId);
                rowCount = results.Rows.Count;
                CallerId = rowCount > 0 ? results.Rows[0][4].ToString() : CallerId;
                if (rowCount > 1)
                {

                    ListView1.DataSource = new DataRow[] { results.Rows[0] };

                    ListView1.DataBind();

                }
```

I got this exception

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'MembershipID'.

Comment: You are missing a check if result is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
ListView1.DataSource = results;
```

if you need only one row to bind, try below

```
ListView1.DataSource =results.AsEnumerable().Take(1).CopyToDataTable();
```